# ng2-codemirror - How to add custom keywords to autocomplete (hint)

Tags: angular, autocomplete, keyword, codemirror

I want to add custom autocomplete list(hint) that get from an API call in a ng2-codemirror editor. I found this solution [[CodeMirror AutoComplete Custom List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244449/codemirror-autocomplete-custom-list) ] from SO.But I'm getting an error when accessing,

```
CodeMirror.hint.javascript // ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'javascript' of undefined
```

This is my component class.

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

import "codemirror/lib/codemirror";
import "codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript";
import "codemirror/addon/hint/show-hint";
import "codemirror/addon/hint/javascript-hint";

declare let CodeMirror: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-editor',
  templateUrl: './editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./editor.component.scss']
})
export class SearchComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('editor') editor;
  query: string = '';

  config = {
    mode: 'javascript',
    lineNumbers: false,
    theme: 'eclipse',
    extraKeys: {"Ctrl-Space": "autocomplete"},
  };

  constructor(private searchService: SearchService) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(this.editor.instance);
    let orig = CodeMirror.hint.javascript; 
    console.log(orig);
  }
}
```

Does anyone know a fix for this issue or any better way to add custom keywords to autocomplete dropdown.

Thanks

Comment: Try with `import * as codemirror from "codemirror";` and remove `declare var`.

Comment: Wow. It's working now. Thank you very much @Patryk Brejdak. Now I can try with keywords from a backend call.