# Overwriting a Javascript function in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, codemirror

I'm using Angular 5 and typescript and included the code editor *codemirror* into my page.

I want to overwrite a nested functionality: **Codemirror.hint.function**

In javascript it looks like:

```
Codemirror.hint.function = function(param) = {
...
}
```

How can I do this in typescript? Because it is nested, I can't define a simple interface.

I want to define an own autocompletion for this editor.

solved it: Codemirror specific solution: Code: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yxvyvj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
Object.defineProperty(Codemirror.hint, 'function', {value: () => {/* your override */}});
```

Although I highly doubt that an object can have a `function` function, since it is a javascript keyword.

**EDIT** I don't know why or how, but the typescript definition in your blitz didn't declare CodeMirror as a global variable. Probably minification, but I won't search further.

So I added the script with a CDN in `index.html`, and now it works.

**[Here is the stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-phyeht?file=app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: Cannot find Codemirror. Should I define an interface ?

Comment: How do you access it in your Typescript component ?

Comment: At the moment i have no possibility to access it. Thats why I'm stuck.

Comment: `declare var Codemirror: any;` ?

Comment: Throws an error, that codemirror is not defined, if i use  it with the functino defineProperty.

Comment: And if you add `declare var Codemirror: any;`, just like I said ?

Comment: I declared it like that.
There is an example how  I want to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244449/codemirror-autocomplete-custom-list

Does it matter where I declare the var? I declared it in the component I want to use it.

Comment: Please post your code, I'm getting really tired of people saying they do something, while they don't, and then complain about the solution not working because they didn't do it just because they didn't like the answer. Or even better, create a stackblitz with your issue.

Comment: Maybe you should have stated that you used typescript definitions, and not a Javascript library ... I don't know Codemirror, what does Codemirror represents ? Is it a global variable ?

Comment: Codemirror is the code editor, that is shown on the side. The namespace Codemirror references to the functionality of the javascript implementation of Codemirror. 

The functionality for a autocompletion of the library is stored in the namespace CodeMirror.hint.functionname.

Comment: Nevermind, I edited my answer, feel free to look at the blitz (sorry about your code in this blitz, but at every change the code mirror was being focused, I lost my mind so I deleted your code to avoid that)

Comment: If the error still pops, make a small modification to let stackblitz import the library from the CDN correctly.